# Create a grid of horizontally and vertically aligned squares that don't overflow the container and remain square upon resizing

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Criteria

1. The cells may not overflow the container
2. The layout should work for any parent size and aspect ratio (e.g., landscape, portrait, x/y)
3. The cells must be centered within their row and their column (the content within the cell does not need to be centered)
4. In my case it has to be a 2*8 grid but the code should be flexible enough to handle any grid size
5. The cells should remain square upon resizing (keep their specified aspect ratio of 1/1)

Here is a working solution that I've managed to come up with (resize the container to see how it behaves on different aspect ratios)

```css
.grid {
    resize: both;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.cell {
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    flex: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: auto;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px  solid blue;
    background-color: #8080ff;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My current solution is functional, but I have a few problems with it:

1. There are too many wrapper elements (2 wrappers per cell). Ideally this should be reduced
2. I would prefer a solution that uses `display: grid;`

I'm trying to learn `display: grid;` layout and this seems like a problem where the obvious choice would be grid, but I've yet to find a solution that uses it.

The solution I've provided is a reference implementation on how it should work. I'm looking for an implementation with the same behavior but one that uses `display: grid;`.

Here is my attempt at using grid layout:

```css
.grid {
    border: 3px solid black;
    resize: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
.cell {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: rgb(255, 161, 161);
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    background-color: rgb(136, 136, 255);
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, my grid solution does not satisfy all of the criteria. The cells are not vertically aligned within their row. The conventional ways of vertically aligning a div broke the layout.

Is this even possible with a pure CSS grid layout or is the use of flex/table/whatever inevitable?

Comment: *My current solution works perfectly, but I have a few problems with it.* isn't that an oxymoron

Comment: @Pete It's behavior is exactly what I want, but in terms of code quality I have issues with it

Comment: If you want to create a grid it’s a good idea to use `display:grid`… As you say it will reduce the amount of wrappers and simplify your code. I’m not sure what exactly the problem is? Have you tried using grid?

Comment: @Kokodoko If I didn't try using grid I wouldn't've had to make this post, the problem with grid was that either: The cells didn't keep their aspect-ratio or The cells overflowed the container or The cells were vertically aligned to the top instead of the middle

Comment: In terms of simplifying the code, you can start by removing the `<div class="grid">`. If I see it correctly, you can add `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` to the `wrap` class and the behavior will be the same

Comment: @IvanBeliakov Thanks for the feedback! In the actual project that wrapper does have a function. But in my minimal reproducable example it loses it's function, and is thus unnecessary. Thanks for pointing it out, I removed it from the post.

Comment: @Kokodoko I added my grid attempt to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trial and error I've managed to come up with a solution.

No wrappers, no flexbox, no table, no container queries just a grid and its children

```css
.grid {
    border: 3px solid black;
    resize: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: grid;
    width: 100px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.cell {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    background-color: rgb(136, 136, 255);
    overflow: hidden;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    
    /* keep the aspect ratio while filling as much space as possible */
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    
    /* center the element */
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [MDN flex container documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container):

```css
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

can center vertically

```css
.grid {
    border: 3px solid black;
    resize: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
.cell {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 5px solid red;
    background-color: rgb(255, 161, 161);
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="cell">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                3
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                5
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                6
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                7
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                8<
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The numbers don't need to be centered but the blue squares containing the numbers do. Also your solution completely disregards the requirement of the 1/1 aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simpler than you realize, and you're closer than you think. In the snippet below I've stripped out the unnecessary wrapper divs and added flexbox to center the cell content.

```css
.grid {
  border: 3px solid black;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  max-width: 200px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.grid > * {
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  background-color: rgb(136, 136, 255);
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  /* center the cell content in both directions */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost correct, but your solution does not keep the 1/1 aspect ratio when the width is larger than the height https://i.imgur.com/Z0grXRy.png

Comment: Also I would like to note that the numbers within the cell are irrelevant, they don't need to be centered sorry if I wasn't perfectly clear in my post. I edited it to not include the numbers anymore.

Comment: The blue square needs to be vertically centered in it's row which is correct in your solution but, as soon as we get to an aspect ratio where the width is bigger than the height your solution breaks

Comment: @kess I don't see any issue with the aspect ratio being more wide than tall; the eight boxes remain centered. Turn on grid inspection in your browser dev tools and see the dotted lines: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDkgh.png It sounds like the only issue you have is that the eight boxes are not remaining square?

Comment: @TylerH "It sounds like the only issue you have is that the eight boxes are not remaining square?" Yes, that is the only issue

Comment: @kess Thank you; I've added that criterion to your list in the question, since it was missing before.

Comment: Sorry. Missed the resizable bit.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear why the grid is given any more than a width and the number of columns. Setting the rows seems redundant once we have set the height of cells in relation to their width (aspect-ratio: 1 / 1)

This snippet strips everything down to the bare essentials. Obviously if you need more structure to deal with whatever you want to put in a cell that can be added, but it will stay inside the cell and is not relevant to getting the basic grid layout that you want.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.grid>* {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border: solid blue 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #8080ff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```